# Skype on Ubuntu 13

Tags: 13.10, skype

I'm not an ubuntu expert but when trying to install skype though terminal I receive this error message:

```
stardust@stardust:~$ sudo apt-get install skype
[sudo] password for stardust: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package skype
```

How can I fix this problem and finally install skype on my laptop?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

open terminal Ctrl+alt+T

then type

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```